# IllegalStateException Happening when App is in MultiWindow

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-7.0-nougat, multi-window

My app is crash in android N+ when is in multiwindow. But this ocurred only MainActivity is actualy activity, others activityes doesn't crash. My MainActivity have tabs fragment, and one of them have childfragment, I don't now if this is relevant, but I have a LocationService running in background. Just below the exception is generating.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3421)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2730)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4524)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1479)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6123)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:867)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:757)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady (FragmentManager.java:1956)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2007)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart (Fragment.java:2214)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1340)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState (FragmentManager.java:1528)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1595)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume (FragmentManager.java:2914)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume (FragmentController.java:223)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments (FragmentActivity.java:509)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume (FragmentActivity.java:498)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume (AppCompatActivity.java:172)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:6800)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:3398)
```

Comment: Are you handling any Save/Restore actions on your Activity? when the app goes into multi-window mode, the system calls `onDestroy()` and then `onCreate()` because the dimensions have changed and the activity needs to be recreated to handle this change.
Now I am guessing you are using a PagerAdapter of some sort to manage your Tabs, if that is indeed the case, Can you please test doing this on the `onCreate()` method of your Activity: `super.onCreate(null);`
And then override the `onRestoreInstanceState()` and remove the `super` call.
This is just to see if that's the reason of the crash.